# Select option depending on GET parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `select`:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="" role="search">
    <select name="m" onchange="this.form.submit()" title="Archive">
        <option value="201503"> march 2015 </option>
        <option value="201501"> january 2015 </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
var archive = getParameterByName('m');
jQuery('select option[value="' + archive + '"').attr('selected', true);

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

The function get's me the value of the param `m` from the URL which I put in the var `archive`. Only thing it doesn't do is setting the attribute selected from the corresponding option.

ie. if the url contains `?m=201501` I want `<option value="201501"> january 2015 </option>` to become `<option value="201501" selected>january 2015</option>` so it's selected in the `select`

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the value of `archive `?

Comment: Whatever value `m` has. ie if `?m=201501` then `archive` has the value `201501`, if  `?m=201502` then `archive` has the value `201502`. checked this by putting it out to the console.

Comment: @LiamdeHaas did u tried to set value to select tag?

Comment: you had a previous question about changing the value of the option element... whether this code is executed before that or after

Comment: @IkaPkhakadze yes, but what has that to do with this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/537kvuva/1/ - it looks fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny after at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set value of select tag like this:

```
var archive = getParameterByName('m');
jQuery('select').val(archive);
```

Examlpe:
https://jsfiddle.net/syuswwfs/

Comment: did it with `jQuery('option').val(archive)` cause the `option` needs to be selected an no the `select`, but works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: `select` tag has a value, not an `option` tag. When you will set a value to `select` tag, it will automatically set `selected` attribute to `option` subtag.
I'm not sure that `jQuery('option').val(archive)` will work fine

Comment: Youre answer didn't work, it gave the `select` an attribute `selected` and not the `option`

Comment: you dont need to add attribute "selected". You need to set Value.

Comment: I added link to jsfiddle. so you can find it there.

Comment: maybe you have no right value of "archive". if so, you have to update your question

Comment: the value of archive is right, When I do what you suggest it doesn't work. Right now i have this `jQuery('option[name="m"]').val(archive);` and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You dont have to do that.
Just copy paste my code: `jQuery('select').val(archive);`

Comment: you cannot set the value to "option" tag as i described in previous comments. you have to set value to SELECT tag. and the value will be the same, that has option tag as attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72559/discussion-between-ika-pkhakadze-and-liam-de-haas).

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
function getUrlParam(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

to read parameter from URL use than this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parameterM = getUrlParam('m');
    //alert(parameterM);
    $("select").val(parameterM); //this is your selected
});
```